# Log4Net localhost addressing issue in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, configuration, log4net, localhost, ip-address

I've recently moved my solution from an XP machine to a Windows7 machine.

I'm using Log4Net in my solution and Log2Console to read it with a UDP

When I use the following config Log2Console doesn't pick up any results:

```
    <appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
        <remoteAddress value="localhost" />
        <remotePort value="7071" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j" />
    </appender>
```

However if I NSLookup to discover my current IP address it does

```
<appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
    <remoteAddress value="192.168.1.64" />
    <remotePort value="7071" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j" />
</appender>
```

127.0.0.1 does not work either.

Can someone explain what has happened and how I can fix it?  I clearly do not want to use a dynamically assigned IP in a source controlled project!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question there is a lot of discussion about Log4Net and IPV6, there are several workarounds provided [here](http://old.nabble.com/Log4net-UDP-Appender-and-Chainsaw-on-Windows-7-td27439707.html) in my case however the issue was the hosts file.

Apparently my box came with both ::1 and 127.0.0.1 addresses commented out for localhost.  I uncommented the IPV4 one and it's working (I suspect this would resolve IPV6 if required, note you need to enable IPV6 in the Log2Console receiver)

Edited: Apparently this is resolved in [v1.2.11](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-112) onwards.

Comment: I've had the same issue in v 1.2.10 and it seems a recent version of Log4Net fixes it - at least v 1.2.11. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-112 - please consider updating your answer.